# Select a single row from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `(4219, 2400)` dimensional numpy array from which I want to get the 10th row. I'm referring to [this page](https://thispointer.com/python-numpy-select-rows-columns-by-index-from-a-2d-ndarray-multi-dimension/) and all methods listed there are returning errors.

e.g. `X[10,:]` returns `'(10, slice(None, None, None))' is an invalid key`

`X[10]` returns a 4219-dimensional vector so I'm assuming that's the 10th column instead of the 10th row. So then I try:

`X.T[10]` which gives me `KeyError: 10`.

Now I'm at a loss, even though it seems like a simple task. How do I get the 10th row of `X`?

Comment: What does `X.shape` return?

Comment: @Brenlla: (4219, 2400)

Comment: @ShirishKulhari could you show a full code example?

Comment: how do you create this array? Maybe it is not numpy array. Check its type `print( type(X) )`

Comment: I test some example and I can get this error when I use `pandas.DataFrame` instead of `numpy.array`

Answer (score 2):

Python and NumPy indexing starts at 0, so the tenth row has index 9.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(4219, 2400)

# make sure you are working with a numpy array
print(type(X))

print(X.shape)

print(X[9, :])
print(X[9])
```

Answer (score -1):

rows,columns (4219, 2400)
x[10] will give 10th row,
x[:10] will give the 10th column

Comment: `x[10]` will be the 11th row. The tenth row is `x[9, :]` or `x[9]`